# GIMP - How to change tool ui size

Tags: gimp

How can I increase the size of the sliders, the are far too small

[image]

Answer (score 1):

GIMP's UI respects system zoom. Change your system's display zoom settings on your computer.

If you also want bigger icons, do *Edit > Preferences > Interface > Icon Theme*.  From the dropdown change "Guess icon size from resolution" to "Custom icon size", and move the slider to from small, to medium, large or huge.

[image]

Comment: I see well this a letdown. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @DanA How is it a let down? It answers your question.

Comment: I assume by `system zoom` you mean the scaling. I am using windows 10 btw

Comment: @DanA Yes . . . I was trying ***not*** to make the answer Windows-specific, because different OS's call it different things. But yes, in Windows 10 right click somewhere on the desktop, choose Display Settings. In the settings under "Scale and Layout", set it to something higher than 100%.

Comment: I already have it set to 150% but thanks for the help anyways

Answer (score 0):

There is an option called "Use Compact Sliders" in *Edit > Preferences > Interface.* It should be exactly what you're looking for. Turn it off to get the old, bigger style of slider back.